# AMD RX480 AMDGPU driver issues

Tags: drivers, unity, 16.10, amd-graphics

I recently installed an RX480 AMD card using just the open-source AMDGPU drivers, and for the most part it works fine.

Unfortunately something goes wrong when the monitors enter stand-by mode, or more to the point: leave stand-by mode.

The screen remains black and only the mouse is visible. Weirdly enough, the mouse does change cursor type when hovering over (what I assume to be) text parts.

[image: Black screen with only mouse cursor visible]

I can switch to another virtual console using the ALT + Function keys, that works fine.

I have also disabled all the energy saving functionality (so "Standby after inactivity" is set to never in both the "Brightness and lock screen" and "Energy/Power management" screen)

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 with the latest amdgpu version 1.2.99 driver from Oibaf's PPA.